# How pass jquery array to request properly

Tags: jquery, arrays, get, request

I have array in jquery and passing it to hidden input and sending to controller through get method.
But when i dump passed request i get not really good array.

```
array:1 [
  0 => "11115,11116,11117,11118,11119,11120,11121,11122,11123,11124,11125,11126,11127,11128,11129"
]

list = []
i pass in script like generatedTicket.attr("value", list);
```

how i can get something like that [0=>11115,1=>11116... and so on] not all data on zero index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pass jquery array to input like string and then in controller used this code.

```
$inputstring = $request->generuoti; (input name)
$newarray = explode(',', $kuponai); (this function made array from string which was posted on request.
```